# How to hide Login fields from the logged user

Tags: javascript, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am developping an ASP MVC using ADO.net. I am trying to hide the login fields after the user login on.

Indeed, after authentication from the home page, the user is redirected to his profil page. The problem is that when the user go back to the home page, he find always the Login Fields.

According to the Debugger, Session["currentUser"] stay always null and then the script is rendered.

I didn't find also an error in dev tools.

This is what I've tried :

```
 @if (Session["currentUser"] != null)
 {
    <script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").hide();
});
    </script>
 }
        <div class="login" id="login">
            @*@RenderPage("~/Views/Home/Login.cshtml")*@
            <link href="~/Content/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <div class="main-w3l">
                <div class="w3layouts-main" style="background-image:url('/template/web/images/bg3.jpg'); margin-top:50px;">
                    <h2>Login Now</h2>


                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                    {


                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                        <input value="E-MAIL" name="Email" type="email" required="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-Mail';}" />
                        <input value="PASSWORD" name="Password" type="password" required="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'password';}" />
                        <span><input type="checkbox" />Remember Me</span>
                        <h6><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></h6>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <input type="submit" value="login" name="login">

                    }

                    <p>Don't Have an Account ?<a href="#" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Create", "Client") + "'") ;">Register Now</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**UPDATE :**
Controller :

```
  public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

    database_Access_layer.db dblayer = new database_Access_layer.db();


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection fc, string LastName, string Email)
    {

        int res = dblayer.Admin_Login(fc["Email"], fc["Password"]);
        if (res == 1)
        {
            Session["currentUser"] = Email;
            string z = Email;
            connection();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Email from Client", con);

            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                con.Close();
            }
            foreach (string x in result)
            {
                if (x == z)
                {

                    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand($"select LastName from Client WHERE Email= '{x}' ", con);
                    con.Open();
                    string y = command2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    con.Close();
                    Session["currentUser"] = y;

                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Profil", "Client");
            Session.RemoveAll();


        }
        else {

            TempData["msg"] = " Email or Password is wrong !";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }

    }
```

Comment: which version of .net is this? .net core or .net framework?

Comment: mvc 5, .net core

Comment: well mvc 5 isn't under .net core. .net core has mvc 6 and mvc 5 comes under .net framework

Comment: @NevilleNazerane :  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>

Comment: do you have a `web.config` file in your project?

Comment: yes and I copied the line in the last comment from it

Comment: if you have a `web.config` file it isn't .net core btw.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane ok thx

Answer (score 2):

There are built in systems to help you with the login. Session variables shouldn't be used for several reasons.

To set the login, you can use the following function inside your controller:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, remember);
```

Similarly you can use `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` for logging out.

Now within your razor or in any controller you can check for `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to verify if the user is logged in.

For this functionality to work, you also need to make sure you have the following under your web.config, under your `<system.web>`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">

</authentication>
```

Further more if you would like to take advantage of this login feature, you can add your login form into a separate cshtml page different from your home page. Lets say this page is in the location `Home/Login`. Now you can modify the above code within web.config as follows

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

This assigns your default login page. Now if any URL needs to only be accessed on login, it would automatically redirect to this location if the user is not logged in. To specify that an action needs authentication, use `[Authorize]` before the action or the entire controller if you need the whole controller authorized. Your action will look something like this:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(){
    return View()
}
```

Finally your sample `HomeController` can look something like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();  // for the login form
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Login(string UserName, .... <other fields>)
    {
        // validate your login first here
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggest but I want to mention that I am not using EF, I don't have account controller, my login Action is in HomeController but I tried what you suggest there, another thing, there is two web config in the project which one shall I modify it

Comment: This doesn't use use EF. account controller is just an example. You can do everything within the HomeController as well. But the login action you have is for submitting your login information. You need to make another action anywhere. returning a view for the login html form. 
You need to modify the web.config in the main folder not the one inside the views folder.

Comment: I have a login action that return another view. Can please see my update in the code

Comment: yeah i just updated the code. Also never let an action you are posting to return another view. If a form posts to an action, use one of the `Redirect` functions such as `RedirectToAction` to redirect to another action that returns a view.

Comment: in your code, you can replace `Session["currentUser"] = Email;` with ` FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Email, true);`. Then create another function as shown above.

Comment: I didn't understand what shall I keep and what shall I delete in my code

Comment: mainly replace the line i just mentioned above. that is the main. Then, instead of `Session["currentUser"] != null`, use `User.IsAuthenticated`.

Comment: yes I tried but user doen't contain a definition of IsAuthenticated

Comment: try `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and `User.Identity.Name` for getting the username

Comment: This looks great. I'll try it. My only question right now is in web.config, where exactly would I add the <authentication> tags? There's a lot in my web.config and I haven't had to mess with it much except for endpoints.

Comment: I added the above code without the <authentication> tags for now just to get it working and when I authorize in my Account controller and set `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);` and then I redirect to my /Home/Index/ controller action with the [Authorize] attribute, I still get the unauthorized error. Am I missing something?

Comment: The `authentication` tag needs to be inside the `<system.web>` tag. Mostly your web config should have that tag. This tag will set the type of authentication. I don't think authorize will work without the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Store the token/related information from which you know weather the user is logged in or not in sessions/cache, then where ever you are writing user login functionality either you can write any service or just use jquery/javascript to access that, then show or hide form depending on that.

Comment: can you please more explain ?