# Use [Authorize] Attribute Without Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity

I've looked around to try and find an answer to my specific question. I'm basically using an external library to check if a user is authorized within our domain via username and password.

`var authenticatedUser = ECNSecurity.SecurityChecker.AuthenticateUser(model.Username, model.Password);`

Returns true or false whether the user is or is not. I'd like to be able to use the [Authorize] attribute on some of my controller methods. Is this possible to do this without using Identity? Or would I need to get Identity and create my own user which inherits the Identity UserModel? Then when I mark that user as authenticated, somehow, the [Authorize] attribute will be picked up?

I am watching tutorials and reading but I do have a more specific kind of use case for this that I can't find a direct answer for. Excuse my inexperience in this security/authorize area if I'm asking something too silly. Maybe what I'm failing to realize is that the [Authorize] attribute will only work with Identity users.

Any input would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: which version of mvc is this?

Comment: Should be the exact latest. 5.2.3 from what it says in NuGet packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need ASP.NET Identity if you just want Authorize filter to work.

You just need ***OWIN Cookie Middleware*** in ASP.NET MVC. You could also add claims such as username, if you want.

Here are few steps you need -

### [Startup.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Startup.cs)

Configure OWIN Cookie Middleware at startup.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourApplication.Startup))]
namespace YourApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### [OwinAuthenticationService](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Security/OwinAuthenticationService.cs#L10)

```
public class OwinAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _context;
    private const string AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie";

    public OwinAuthenticationService(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void SignIn(User user)
    {
        IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
        };

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthenticationType);

        IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

        authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.Authentication;

        authenticationManager.SignOut(AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

*You can look at my working sample project at [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin).*

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look at your example.

Comment: Can I ask... What if I don't have a Startup.cs? Can I add this and it will be implemented? I created a blank ASP.NET template and this startup doesn't seem to have been included.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't use OWIN Middleware by default. So, you will have to add `Startup.cs` by yourself.

Comment: to add the start up you will find "startup" as one of the options in the "add new item" window in vs

Comment: I am working on this OWIN auth but it's proving a little more difficult than it seems due to my newbish-ness here. I may need to study up some more on this OWIN middleware if I have the time here.

Comment: The line `IOwinContext context = _context.Request.GetOwinContext();` is showing red under the `GetOwinContext()` method. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Could you ensure you installed all [dependencies](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/packages.config) via NuGet?

Comment: I can. I made sure I had the same using statements. I'll check against your dependencies. I tried to run just to see what the error list would say and it does say I may be missing a reference to HttpRequestBase, but searching NuGet and searching the "Add Reference" list doesn't have anything for this. I have been using much of your example project to create mine and the code is very impressive. I appreciate its availability.

Comment: I did get form authentication to work which the above user posted but I'd like to know how to get the above working so I'm going to continue. I'll report back about the dependency match against your application.

Comment: I don't have entity framework, I didn't want to add more than I needed... Maybe that's what I need.

Comment: Sorry for the flood of comments but looks like it was the `System.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` so I'm going to turn off forms authentication and see if I can get this working.

Comment: Ok just to be complete here. I believe I did get this way fully working. I don't yet understand all of it and since I don't have dependency injection yet setup I had to recreate things a few different way... But I think I can make this work and add DI. Thanks again for sharing all of this.

Comment: You're quite welcome. I'm glad that you figure it out.

Comment: It's crazy to see where I was a year ago and where I am now lol. That OWIN auth was great I remember it. I modified it some to work with what I needed but couldn't have created anything near it without it being shared. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To authorize with cookies in the .net framework versions of mvc, you can simply use the following

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, remember);
```

`remember` is a boolean that is equivalent to "remember me" option.

Check my answer here for more info in the set up if needed [How to hide Login fields from the logged user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282620/how-to-hide-login-fields-from-the-logged-user/47283002#47283002)

Comment: This is the only code that would be needed to authorize for that instant of usage?

Comment: I'll check your link first. Thank you for the post.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `FormsAuthentication`, but it is 15 years old technology. Now, we have a better solution - OWIN Middleware; I highly recommend using OWIN Middleware, if you plan to migrate to ASP.NET Core in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I did get this forms authentication working but I'll see if I can get OWIN middleware working.

Comment: True OWIN is a more professional approach. But to just login, right now, this line should be fine.