# How to retrieve identity claim values in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I am googling for this thing for quit a long time but still can't get proper answer. I am using identity claim for user authentication and I need some claim values in my _Layout.cshtml page. However I can retrieve custom identity claim values but not built in ones.

Here I set my identity:

```
 var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(
                new[] { 
                    // adding following 2 claim just for supporting default antiforgery provider
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.LoginId),
                    new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.UserName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid,user.UserId.ToString()),
                    new Claim("OperationType", user.OperationType.ToString()),
                    new Claim("ImageLink", user.ImageLink.ToString())

                },
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(ident);
            // Set current principal
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
```

and my layout page code:

```
@using System.Security.Claims;
...........
@{  
    string userDesignation = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("OperationType").Value; ;
    string userImage = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("ImageLink").Value; ;

}
```

I can retrieve my custom claims(*ImageLink,OperationType*) values but couldn't able to retrieve (*Name,Sid*) with the same pattern. Some of answers I found that said about Extension methods. Is that only way for retrieve values or have any other way? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This type of logic should never be in a view (or layout).  Instead you should create a `LayoutController` with a method you call from your layout with  `html.RenderPartial()`.

Comment: Can you not use OWIN Authentication Middleware? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47579495/296861)

Answer (score 3):

Please use threading namespace in top of your layout page

```
@using System.Threading;
```

and access your claim types as following

```
@{  
string userDesignation = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("OperationType").Value;
string userImage = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("ImageLink").Value;


var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

    // Get the claims values
    var id= identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Sid)
        .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
    var s = id;
//so on.......
}
```

But @Erik Philips is right. You should use those logic as partial.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a LayoutController with a method you call from your layout with html.RenderPartial() (from comment below @Erik Philips).

```
TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
var claimsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
var displayNameClaim = (claimsIdentity == null) ? null : claimsIdentity.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == ApplicationUser.DisplayNameClaimType);
var nameToDisplay = (displayNameClaim == null) ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name : displayNameClaim.Value;
var nameToDisplayTitle = myTI.ToTitleCase(nameToDisplay);
```

In the view, the name value is injected into a `<span class="NameDisplay"></span>`.

```
$(".NameDisplay").html(@Html.Raw("\"" + nameToDisplayTitle + "\""));
```

In `IdentityModels.cs`, I define the following field:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public const string DisplayNameClaimType = "FirstName";
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    //etc.
}
```

and define this claim:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
    // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    // Add custom user claims here
    userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(DisplayNameClaimType, FirstName));
    return userIdentity;
}
```

Comment: This type of logic should never be in a view (or layout).  Instead you should create a `LayoutController` with a method you call from your layout with  `html.RenderPartial()`.

Comment: Constructive comment